# Problem in multiple image upload in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I got an error in laravel 8, while uploading multiple images.

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize()

> must be of the type array, string given, called in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_cms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php
> on line 886

Here is my code in controller:

```
 $gallery =  new GalleryImage; 
 foreach( $req->file('image_name') as $image)
   {
     $upload_image_name = time().'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
     $image->move('uploads', $upload_image_name);    
     $name[] = $upload_image_name;         
   } 
    $gallery->image_name = $name;        
    $gallery->save();         
    return redirect()->back()->with('status','Image Uploaded Successfully.');
```

Code in blade:

```
<input name="image_name[]" id="exampleFile" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
```

If I return `$req->file('image_name')` file is showing empty

Comment: `$req->file('image_name')` doesn't exist here, because `$req->image_name'` is an **array**, the array values contain the image. If this is a single image, then change `name="image_name[]"` to `name="image_name"` then your code will work

Comment: @sta I am getting null if I `return $req->image_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like issue is due to storing array values in database fields .If you are trying to store images in comma separated then

```
$gallery->image_name = implode(', ',$name);
```

or
change

```
 $name[] = $upload_image_name;
```

to

```
 $name[]['image_name'] = $upload_image_name;
```

and for storing

```
GalleryImage::insert($name);
```